# C# what event to catch UserControl disposed of?

Tags: c#, winforms

What would be the event to catch when a `UserControl` is disposed of in C# ? I'd like to catch it to do some clean up, but after viewing the list of events available in the designer, it seems there is no such thing ?

Comment: How are you creating the user control?

Comment: It's a pane in a VSTO C# addin

Comment: so concretely, I extend it (well I create it using the designer, as simple as that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the [Disposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.disposed.aspx) event is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a "Disposing" event so that some cleanup can be done before the usercontrol is actually disposed?

Comment: @hrh Its not an event, however you can override the [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9yzd5cx.aspx) method of your user control - this is where you should be cleaning up resources (make sure you still call the base implementation)

Answer (score 13):

When you create the user control a Dispose method is created automatically for you in the yourUserControlName.Designer.cs file. Add whatever clean up code that method. You may want to change the auto generated code to something like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            // your clean up code here
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

That way your clean up code will not be dependent on the components object.

Comment: Proposal: do the cleanup before the components are disposed, especially if you need the components for the cleanup. For instance if you have a user control with a bindingsource of which the data needs to be serialized when the user control is disposed: you need to be able to access the bindingsource to serialize the items

Comment: You can move this code into your yourUserControlName.cs file so you do not have to change any code in the designer file manually.

Comment: You may also override `OnHandleDestroyed` which will be called when the underlying HWnd is destroyed, usually when the parent form is closed.